# Asynchronous REST API with Jersey

Tags: multithreading, rest, tomcat, asynchronous, jersey

We are using Jersey for a REST webservice (deployed on tomcat).

I know that

- Tomcat's HTTP connector has a thread pool for reading HTTP requests and forwarding to Jersey.
- Forwarding to Jersey is synchronous.

I read [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html#d0e10297) that Jersey provides `AsyncService` to maximise concurrency.

Question:
Why does Jersey's async design force developer to offload REST processing to separate thread/runnable, while Jersey can do this by itself with a dedicated/private executor pool?

Is this for better control for developer or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why does Jersey's async design force developer to offload REST processing to separate thread/runnable, while Jersey can do this by itself with a dedicated/private executor pool?

You're not *forced* to. Jersey has the [`@ManagedAsync`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.21/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ManagedAsync.html) that you can put on your methods. This does exactly what you are asking

> #### ManagedAsync
>
> Indicates that the resource method to which the annotation has been applied should be executed on a separate thread managed by an internal Jersey executor service.

```
@GET
@ManagedAsync
public void longGet(@Suspended final AsyncResponse ar) {
    
}
```

**See Also:**

- [Server Asynchronous Managed Example](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/server-async-managed)